# Playing audio files in android

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, playback

I need to play long audio files using the Android SDK. I am aware of the MediaPlayer framework shipped by Android, but I was wondering wether the built-in "Music Player" application could be invoked, so I don't have to write my own player GUI and code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** 
Set up an intent like this:

```
act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=file:///mnt/sdcard/song_name.mp3 typ=audio/mpeg3
```

Action: [VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri
                .parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/song_name.mp3"),
                "audio/mpeg3");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: the `correct` way (or perhaps less-frowned upon way) to access the SD card is using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. This would change your file String to `Uri.parse("file:///" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/song_name.mp3")`

Comment: Yup. Thanks @Phil. I missed that.